# Remove Duplicates from string,Without using HASHMAP and O(n) time complexity

Tags: string, performance, algorithm

***Microsoft Interview Question***

> Remove Duplicates from string,Without using HASHMAP and O(n) time complexity

There is a solution in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity, but the interview question specifically mentions NO HASHMAP and O(n) time.

Any pointers are appreciated, because I can't think anything lower than O(n log n) time, which employs sorting and does use O(n) space.

Comment: Do you mean "remove duplicate chars"?

Comment: Yes i do mean the same .

Comment: SO is less about "is it possible" and more about finding practical solutions.

Comment: What is a “string”? A sequence of bytes? A sequence of UTF-16 codepoints? Something else?

Comment: Does the question also specifically say you can't use hashmaps?

Comment: Yes it SPECIFICALY say you cant use hashmaps..i think i have mentioned it pretty clearly.

Comment: @Spandan do you have a written version of the question?

Comment: @SAM:not right now,i will post in a bit...but what diffrence will it make ?

Comment: @Spandan It will let us know if there are any other unusual stipulations that you haven't told us yet(like the no hash sets part).

Comment: Are we allowed to use an auxiliary array of size 26 to store the count of characters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do a sort of bucket sort.

- make an array containing every single char
- make an array containing a count for it's corresponding char

The only reason we're using 2 arrays like this is because you specifically disallowed hash maps.  You can represent this structure however you please.  If you're allowed to convert chars to `int`s, you need only use 1 array.

Since we're assuming a limited number of possible characters, Each array will be constant size, or **O(1)**

- Iterate over your string, and increment the `count` for each `char` you find.  If count is already greater than `0` you've found a duplicate.

searching your char array for a particular char takes **O(1)** time, because there is a limited number of chars.

you will do this search n times for a net run-time of **O(n)**

---

If arrays are no good, than you can make a linked list to hold only values that you've found.  It will still be constant because the size of the linked list is still bound by the number of possible characters.

If you do it that way, you'll more or less be doing the exact same thing, except it cosmetically look less like a bucket-sort strategy.

Comment: oh man,i said NO EXTRA SPACE..that's the question actualy,else hashmap solution is trivial n well known .

Comment: A pre-defined fixed size (in english it's of size 26) hashmap is no extra space

Comment: @Spandan O(1) space doesn't mean no extra space.

Comment: ok,let me me Update the question .

Comment: @Spandan Do you have a written version of the question?

Comment: would you mind removing your answwr,not that i Updated the question.

Comment: @Spandan, there's no need to remove this question because it's absolutely correct. It's your interpretation of the question that is in error.

Comment: @Spandan - But his answer is still correct, it's O(1) space.

Comment: We cant use a Hashmap,please see the Updated heading of question .

Comment: Assuming the input string is very large compared to the consisting character this answer fulfills the constraints

Comment: @Spandan This answer doesn't use any hashing algorithm, so it's not a hashmap.

Comment: @Spandan- This answer satisfies all of your constraints - it runs in O(n) time and uses O(1) space.  Remember that O(1) space doesn't mean "no extra storage space."  It means "using at most a constant amount of auxiliary storage space."  Since there are only a constant number of characters possible in a string, a hash map containing them will use only O(1) auxiliary storage space.  The constant might be large, but it's still a constant.

Comment: what are you people,nuts?.....this statement of his answer ,"You have an array or map representing all the possible characters indexed by character value, ",means a HASHMAP.

Comment: @Spandan That's not a HASHmap, because it doesn't use hashing.

Comment: @Spandan, perhaps technically an array could be considered a subset of a hashmap, where the hash is the identity function and there's no possibility of collision. But most people don't view it that way, probably including your interviewer. It's really a magnitude of difference.

Comment: @SamIam - another option (if the string is in english) is to use an `int` to store the data as a bitwise array - where the LSB is `a` and MSB is `z` so for example if we want to check if char C already exists we do something like `notAhash & (1<<(C - 'a' ))` and if we want to set char C we just do `notAhash |= 1<<(C - 'a' );` and of course we initialize it: `notAhash = 0`. But really it's the same thing.

Comment: or you can just start bit-wise `or`-ing all the chars together and see if it changes the value of the aggregate.

Answer (score 3):

I might have another solution, i think it's far worse, but it works for small character arrays. The algorithm is as follows:

> 1. We assign each letter to a prime number starting from 2. - This will be our look up table.
> 2. We find the product of all the numbers. -> O(n)
> 3. In a loop -> O(n) we check if product % k*k == 0    if it is, we have found a duplicate k.

This solution stores only 1 number, but will easily overflow. The prime table will take much space though.

EDIT:
If we add a constraint that there are only 40 unique characters available, we could use the Euler's quadratic polynomial to find the primes.

> P(n) = n*n − n + 41

This does not need any additional space, besides the product.

Comment: If you only store the 1 number, than how do you assign a different prime to each character?

Comment: @SamIam since we have a limited set of characters, we could create a lookup table before

Comment: But then we're back to the exact same gripe that the OP had with the bucket-sort method.  We have `O(C)` storage space  with `C` being the number of legal characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
traverse the list for i= 0 to n-1 elements
{
  check for sign of A[abs(A[i])] ;
  if positive then
     make it negative by   A[abs(A[i])]=-A[abs(A[i])];
  else  // i.e., A[abs(A[i])] is negative
     this   element (ith element of list) is a repetition
}
```

You can easily modify it for 0 in the array. In case of characters you can use its integer code.